# Modelformset with dynamic form addition saves only the first form

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates

I have two forms  on one page, each with its own submit button. With JS script I can dynamically add a new formset for each of the two form.  I am faced with a situation where I can add as many new forms as I want for the form that is displayed first on the page and all are saved. For the second forms list, only the first form from the formset list is saved.

**template.html**

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset_planguage.management_form }}
    <div id="form_set_lang">
{% for form in formset_planguage.forms %}
{{form.non_field_errors}}
        {{form.errors}}
        <table class='no_error'>
            {{ form }}
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more_lang">
<div id="empty_form_lang" style="display:none">
    <table class='no_error'>
        {{ formset_planguage.empty_form }}
    </table>
</div>
 <input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" name="language" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset_framework.management_form }}
    <div id="form_set_framework">
{% for form in formset_framework.forms %}
{{form.non_field_errors}}
        {{form.errors}}
        <table class='no_error'>
            {{ form }}
        </table>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
<input type="button" value="Add More" id="add_more_framework">
<div id="empty_form_framework" style="display:none">
    <table class='no_error'>
        {{ formset_framework.empty_form }}
    </table>
</div>
 <input class='btn btn-primary' type="submit" name="framework" value="Submit"/>
</form>


<script> 
$('#add_more_framework').click(function() {
    var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form_set_framework').append($('#empty_form_framework').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});
</script>

<script>
$('#add_more_lang').click(function() {
    var form_idx = $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
    $('#form_set_lang').append($('#empty_form_lang').html().replace(/__prefix__/g, form_idx));
    $('#id_form-TOTAL_FORMS').val(parseInt(form_idx) + 1);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two forms are like `<form method="post" action="">` so the destination is *always* the same page, so Django will handle both forms the same way. If in your page you handle in the `POST` the values of the first form, the second will be handled like it's the first form.

The best solution is to send one "big" form with all your fields named differently in the first "group" and the second "group", and read only either the first "group" or if it's empty, the second "group".

The other solution is to send the second form to a different url.

Comment: @OliverPons what do you mean by fields named differently? And about other solution - send form to different url, I need to process all the forms on one page.

Comment: In your loops when you do `{{ form }}` it generates names like `<input name="field_1">` and so on, you could do your own loop and make your own "`name`" but this is complex. The second solution might be better.

Comment: In this story, I am confused by the fact that without JS code, when I put several forms into the template, I use the extra=2 parameter, for example, both forms work fine. It seems to me that I don't change the logic of Django when adding JS code, although I may be wrong. But here's the other problem, I can't send an empty forms. I get form_invalid()

Comment: The second tip is one form - one template?

Comment: when you get form_invalid it means that you've send invalid fields like empty fields that are not allowed to be empty for example. And for the second type is one form, and one *destination* = the `action=""` should be filled with and url like for example `action="http://other_handle_of_form2"`